# How can I reuse an old password?

Tags: password, passwd

I recently changed my password on my [VMware Photon OS](https://vmware.github.io/photon/) host. Now I want to reset it to the old one again, but `passwd` does not let me do it and displays the following message:

```
Password has been already used. Choose another.
passwd: Have exhausted maximum number of retries for service
passwd: password unchanged
```

Can I override this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be aware that reusing old passwords may impose [security risks](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/20591/230952).

The password history is stored at `/etc/security/opasswd`. You can either just remove the lines concerning specific users or delete the history for all users all at once:

```
cat /dev/null > /etc/security/opasswd
```

Answer (score 2):

in addition to removing or clearing the `/etc/security/opasswd` file, look in `/etc/pam.d/system-auth` and `/etc/pam.d/passowrd-auth` and if it contains something resembling

```
password    requisite     pam_pwhistory.so use_authtok remember=24
```

just remove all instances of the `remember=#` for the time being to allow reuse of an existing password.  Then once set you can restore the  `remember=#`