# How to login as root user after deleting system-auth

Tags: root, pam

I wanted to use an old password for my account. 
I am using OpenEuler OS distribution. 
After searching on Stack Exchange, I found this link.

[How can I reuse an old password?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/733694/how-can-i-reuse-an-old-password)

I followed the exact same steps listed below:

> in addition to removing or clearing the `/etc/security/opasswd` file,
> look in `/etc/pam.d/system-auth` and `/etc/pam.d/password-auth`
> and if it contains something resembling
>
> ```
> password    requisite     pam_pwhistory.so use_authtok remember=24
> ```
>
> just remove all instances of the `remember=#` for the time being
> to allow reuse of an existing password. 
> Then once set you can restore the `remember=#`

After that, I am unable to login to the root user. 
I cannot even ssh the server using any user. 
What do I need to do?

Answer (score 2):

The general advice for lock-outs like this is to get a live-version of Linux and boot from that. Mount your disk and undo the change.

And because not everybody reads the comments: as [chris-davies](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/100397/) said: keep a terminal with a root-shell open when you are changing authentication-things and keep a copy of the original files.

Note that removing the `remember=#` from the `pam_pwhistory.so` will probably make the default active, which is 10:

> ```
>    remember=N
>       The last N passwords for each user are saved. The default is
>       10. Value of 0 makes the module to keep the existing contents
>       of the opasswd file unchanged.
> ```

Also, you will want to make sure that  `pam_pwhistory.so` is not the last module in your list.

Comment: I'd also [_strongly_ recommend](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/768602/100397) that any changes to the PAM configuration files are done while keeping a root shell open, and that copies of original files are kept, so that a roll-back is easily possible